# Outlook toolbar button icon

Tags: vb6, outlook

I have the following ***old*** VB6 working code to add a custom button (in a new toolbar) in Outlook

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim objIns As Object
Dim objCBar As Object
Dim lpobjButton As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objIns = oApp.ActiveExplorer
Set objCBar = objIns.CommandBars.Add(barra)

Set lpobjButton = objCBar.Controls.Add()
With lpobjButton
    .Caption = "myLabel"
    .HyperlinkType = 1
    .ToolTipText = "myLink"
End With
```

I'm trying to add an image to the button, but when I execute the following

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim objIns As Object
Dim objCBar As Object
Dim lpobjButton As Object

Dim picPicture As IPictureDisp

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objIns = oApp.ActiveExplorer
Set objCBar = objIns.CommandBars.Add(barra)
Set picPicture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture(App.Path & "\myimage.bmp")

Set lpobjButton = objCBar.Controls.Add()
With lpobjButton
    .Caption = "myLabel"
    .Picture = picPicture  '<--- runtime error 8000ffff here
    .HyperlinkType = 1
    .ToolTipText = "myLink"
End With
```

I get a runtime error

```
(8000ffff) when assigning picPicture to .Picture. 
myimage.bmp is a 16x16 image (256 color)
```

- I also tried with 32x32 pixels (256 color) but no luck. 
  I'm using `OL 2007`

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Did you try `Set .Picture = picPicture`?

Comment: yes, I did, with the same error. thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to use the PasteFace method which copies the picture from the clipboard. Of course that means you have to put your picture on the clipboard first.

```
With lpobjButton
    .Caption = "myLabel"
    Clipboard.Clear
    Clipboard.SetData picPicture, vbCFBitmap
    .PasteFace
    ''.Picture = picPicture  '<--- runtime error 8000ffff here
    .HyperlinkType = 1
    .ToolTipText = "myLink"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Beaner, this works! How can I add transparency? (I hoped to be able to use .Mask in the original approach). And, more, how can I prevent deleting clipboard (possibly written by another process)?

Comment: This is a link to a Microsoft article describing also pasting a mask to the clipboard, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288771. As for preventing the clipboard from being deleted, I don't know that you can or why you would want to. You are only using it as an intermediary step. After pasting the image into your button the clipboard no longer matters.

Comment: the Microsoft link is really interesting. I'm still not able to have their example working, but probably it is a stupid error on my side.